# Liouville's theorem to show ergodicity?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, complex-systems, ergodicity

> a) Consider a harmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian $H=(1/2)(p^2+q^2)$ show that any phase space trajectory $x(t)$ with energy $E$, on the average, spend equal time in all regions of the constant energy surface $Γ(E)$.

I have seen answers to this questions but I simply dont understand it. Is it possible to use Liouville's theorem to show that?

This is the answer I seen to this questions. I understand that q and p comes from solving harm osc. How do we know this is a circle? And the last one how is it shown that the velocity is constant?

a) Let
$p=r\cosϕ;q=r\sinϕ$
The constant energy surface Γ(E) in the $q$−$p$ plane is the circle $r=$const. The equations of motion can be written $r˙=0;ϕ˙=$const, i.e., the phase space point moves with constant velocity and covers the whole "surface". It thus spends equal time in all regions of $Γ(E)$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Liouville's theorem for that.

We know that
$$p=r\cosϕ,\; q=r\sinϕ$$
describes a circle because... well, this is the [parametric equation of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) of radius $r$ centered on the origin of the plane $p$-$q$.

And, if you solve Hamilton's equations of motion for this system, you'll see that $\phi = \omega t$, where $\omega$ is a constant: so $\dot \phi = d\phi/dt = \omega = \text{const.}$

Then, if the this velocity $\phi$ is constant, it means that the time a trajectory spends over an arbitrary region (arc length) $\Delta s$ of the energy surface $\Gamma(E)$ is given by:
$$ \Delta t = \frac{\Delta s}{\omega}, $$
thus, on regions of equal surface (here, length $\Delta s$), the trajectory spends equal time.

In this sense, the statement of the problem seems a bit inaccurate, since it claims equal times for *all* regions, not specifically all regions *of equal surface*.

Comment: But this assumes we've set the units of p such that it is a circle. What if I used different units such that $p = m \omega r \cos \phi, q = r \sin \phi$? Then I would have an ellipse with the arc length traveled in a certain time being dependent on where on the ellipse I am...

Comment: @DavidHambraeus If you changed $p$ like that, the form of the Hamiltonian, which a premise of the problem, would change too.

Comment: Well, there must be some implicit constants in that hamiltonian anyway no? You can't just add a momentum and a length. A dimensionally consistent hamiltonian would be $H = p^2/2m + 1/2 * m \omega^2 q^2$.

Comment: @DavidHambraeus You're right it's an ellipse in general and I'd expect (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) the angular velocity to stay constant, so it wouldn't be true anymore that trajectories "spend equal time in all regions" — this would be true only for the specially chosen coordinates.